# Why shouldn't I modify the UINavigationController's toolbar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

The documentation for the `toolbar` property in UINavigationController says:

> This property contains a reference to the built-in toolbar managed by the navigation controller. Access to this toolbar is provided solely for clients that want to present an action sheet from the toolbar. You should not modify the UIToolbar object directly.

I can understand why I shouldn't modify the toolbar's visibility or items, because UINavigationController provides an interface to do that. But I've added a button that, when tapped, causes the toolbar to animate offscreen. Why shouldn't I do this?

Must I instead create my own ToolbarNavigationController class that replicates everything UINavigationController does with the toolbar just sod, I can do what I want with the toolbar? Seems like a waste of effort when the UINavigationController already does what I want. Why on earth would the docs suggest I so severely limit what I do with it?

Comment: UINavigationControllers are notoriously picky about their exposed properties.  I don't think you're likely to find a good answer that isn't speculation here.

Comment: @CodaFi while that would not surprise me, it doesn't offer much  in the way of satisfaction. :-( Who knows, maybe someone actually knows!

Comment: what would you do to said toolbar if you could access it and modify it? (PS, there may be some closeted apple employees on SO with this knowledge, but I do not think they'd be willing to part with it so easily ;p).

Comment: Frankly, all I'm doing is animating it offscreen. That's it. I have a button that, when tapped, moves the toolbar offscreen and then moves a different toolbar on. The different toolbars represent different modes. I really don't think anyone would object in this case; it's just that comment in the docs that gives me pause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways that having moved the navigation bar might confuse it:

1. If your app can be rotated, does it stay in the right place after rotation?  When it returns to the screen, does it animate on from the right place?
2. If you display a search bar, the navigation bar animates itself off.  If it's already been moved manually, does it know where it is?
3. If you push a `viewController` with [hidesBottomBarWhenPushed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/hidesBottomBarWhenPushed) set to `YES`, and return, does the `navigationController` put its toolbar back where it belongs?

On the other hand, how about calling [UINavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden%3aanimated%3a) - does that do what you want, while letting the navigation controller maintain control of its toolbar?

**Edit**: Sorry about misreading.  Yes, you probably can do what you're asking, as long as you don't also do anything (like item 3 above) that mean the `navigationController` moves its toolbar around.

On the other hand, the behavior you want can also be achieved as follows:

1. For the `viewController` with the multiple toolbars, set its `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES`.
2. Place **all** the toolbars that `viewController` needs on it, and have it take full control of their positions and visibility.

If the default toolbar has the same layout as the navigationController's own toolbar, this will create the odd visual effect of seeing the same set of toolbar items slide off and then on again, but everything else should work.

Comment: It's not the navigation bar I want to mess with (my app has it hidden, not using it at all). It's the toolbar. And no, [`-setToolbarHidden:animated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden:animated:) does not do what I want, because it resizes the view currently being displayed.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, but since one of the other things I plan to do is change the push and pop animations, I might as well write my own ToolbarNavigationController. (I actually [started one already](https://github.com/lunar-theory/LTToolbarNavController).) But for now, it seems that animating the UINavigationController toolbar, so will probably stick with it for the time being. As you say (and @CodaFi seems to agree), it probably won't do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

UIToolbar is inaccessible because it doesn't need to ***be*** accessible.  It responds to +appearance just fine.  In your case, you can access the properties of a readonly variable (look at CGRect!).  If you need to animate a UIToolbar or UINavigatiomBar offscreen, set it's frame.center property equal to a CGPointMake in a UIView animation block.

Comment: I do. Well, similar (I change the frame). My question is: why shouldn't I?

Comment: You should.  Im doing it now.

Comment: Where do you change the frame of the toolbar? Is it still working cleanly in iOS 8?